# is null vs like isnull(@param, '%') mystery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure with a parameter called @MatterNumber that has a default value of  null. In the where clause there is the following line:

```
and (m.Name like @MatterName or @MatterName is null)
```

When testing the proc against against some data it takes over 30 seconds to execute. If I replace the above line with the one below it executes almost straight away. What is the difference between the two lines and why?

```
and m.Name like isnull(@MatterName, '%')
```

Comment: could be the `OR` condition that slows down the query.

Comment: Problem with the first query is that database engine has to provide one query plan which satisfies both null and non-null value of `@MatterName`. It's already proven that this approach is not really fast. The most common approach to avoid that is by `if`/`else` and two different queries. Your `isnull` can be another way to solve that, because `like '%'` can be probably (I'm not 100% sure) just skipped during optimization phase.

Comment: @Marcin - correct, unless m.Name is null itself. So there will be a comparison but SQL Server is smart enough to reduce it to "m.Name is not null".

Comment: Thanks Simon, you helped me realise that there is a difference between the two lines. If m.Name and @MatterName are both null then the top one returns true and the bottom one false. Any suggestions as to a better way of writing the top one would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: Did you try to switch both conditions of your fist line? Like this: `AND (@MatterName IS NULL OR m.Name LIKE @MatterName)`?